# I need help to form if else condition in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I need to form the if else condition in my code. I am comparing two list with each other and print if there is any different item in each list or there isn't any. My code is below.

```
title_check = [[y for y in xml_title_list if y not in json_title_list], [y for y in json_title_list if y not in xml_title_list]]
if len(title_check [0]):
    print("Type which are unmatched in XML are ", title_check [0])

if len(title_check [1]):
    print("Type which are unmatched in JSON are ", type_check[1])

else:
    print("No Unmatched type found")
```

I want to combine ***both if conditions*** and want to run it every time. if they don't execute i want else then. Right now it is only taking **else** condition for second **if** condition.
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag as shown in the other answer. Another way to do this is

```py
if len(title_check[0]) or len(title_check[1]):
    if len(title_check[0]):
        print("Type which are unmatched in XML are ", type_check[0])

    if len(title_check[1]):
        print("Type which are unmatched in JSON are ", type_check[1])
else:
    print("No Unmatched type found")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.difference`:

```
xml, json = set(xml_title_list), set(json_title_list)
umatched_xml = json - xml
unmatched_json = xml - json

if umatched_xml or unmatched_json:
    if umatched_xml:
        print("Type which are unmatched in XML are ", umatched_xml)
    if umatched_json:
        print("Type which are unmatched in JSON are ", umatched_json)
else:
    print("No unmatched type found")
```

Comment: Although i have found the answer but your approach is good. Still it need to address my question that what if **both if** conditions are false and i have to print something like "there are no unmatched types", where would i put the **else** condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
title_check = [[y for y in xml_title_list if y not in json_title_list], [y for y in json_title_list if y not in xml_title_list]]

is_xml = False    
if len(type_check[0]):
    is_xml = True
    print("Type which are unmatched in XML are ", type_check[0])

is_json = False    
if len(type_check[1]):
    is_json = True
    print("Type which are unmatched in JSON are ", type_check[1])

if (not is_xml) and (not is_json):
    print("No Unmatched type found")
```

Comment: You can do this with a single boolean

Comment: True @Sanketh but we don't know if xml and json are all the types that the OP needs to take care of so I've preferred a more modular / expandable approach.